# How to cut a single file into multiple files and save them with different names in UNIX?

Tags: unix

I have a file that contains create table of several tables.
I want to cut the file into multiple parts and save them with name that is present in the script.

For example I have,

```
Create table abc_bcd.xyz , .....
Create table abc_bcd.pqr , ......
```

Now I want my file to be divided for every table and saved with name xyz and pqr.

I tried

```
awk '/CREATE/{x="TABLE"++i ".ddl";}{print > x;}' filename
```

But this gave me files named as TABLE1.ddl , TABLE2.ddl etc.

Thanks in advance.

@shellter Yes, complete create table script is more than one line. 
The file is like:

```
create table abc_bcd.xyz ,
( column1 datatype,
column2 datatype,
......);

create table abc_bcd.pqr ,
( column1 datatype,
column2 datatype,
......);
...
...
...
```

My requirement is to cut the file table wise and save them with name xyz, pqr and so on.

I tried to combine awk and grep but could not achieve my requirement.

Comment: I betting that your `create table ....` really spans more than one line. If so, please update your sample data. That will be a very different sort of problem  However, your current solution is close if the `create`s are really one line each. Let us know. Use the `{}` tool at top left of edit box to format code (after selecting code with mouse). Good luck.

Comment: almost there. take a look at this: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-33

Comment: @shellter Yes, complete create table script is more than one line. The file is like: 
create table abc_bcd.xyz ,
( column1 datatype,
column2 datatype,
......);

create table abc_bcd.pqr ,
( column1 datatype,
column2 datatype,
......);
...
...
...

My requirement is to cut the file table wise and save them with name xyz, pqr and so on.

I tried to combine awk and grep but could not achieve my requirement.

Comment: Does `csplit` (context split) on `create table` work for you?  The file names will be generated (`xx00`, `xx01` unless you specify something else) rather than based on the table names, but it will do the splitting.  You could end up renaming the files based on column 3 of line 1 if you wanted to.